# What is the proper way to use Promise.reject with javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have this following piece of code

```
new Promise((resolve, reject) => { 
    resolve(apiRequest(data))
    reject(console.log('Error'))
}).then(response)
```

Both methods (resolve and reject) are being fired but I want to call reject only when something goes wrong.
How can I throw an error if something goes wrong on that case?

I checked that but it seems like I can not use an If statement to do that check.

```
new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const printResult = apiRequest(data)
    console.log(printResult) //Outputs Promise {<pending>}
    resolve(printResult) //Then it works
    reject(console.log('Error'))
}).then(response)
```

What would be the correct approach to reject a promise?

Comment: Your `apiRequest` already returns a promise, you don't need to manually wrap in in a new promise.

Comment: If `apiRequest` returns a promise you can catch the request failure and reject from there aswell as resolve from the `then` that the request will give you access to.

Alternatively use `async await` with a `try catch`

Comment: Please insert the context of where you use of this code

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest way would be with an `if` condition. i.e

```
new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
   // do something...
   if(somethingGoodHappened) {
      resolve(data)
   } else {
      reject(error)
   }
})
```

But usually when dealing with async requests, the thing you are calling will often be returning a promise, so you can attach the `then` and `catch` callbacks there.

```
apiRequest(data)
.then((result) => {
   // all good
})
.catch((err) => {
   console.log(err)
})
```

Comment: Great, that worked!
Since my apiRequest is returning a promise, I can actually just try await apiRequest(data), right?

Comment: yep, async / await is just a new syntax for handling promises

Answer (score 1):

```js
const mock_api = () => new Promise((res, rej) => {
  const number = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1);
  setTimeout(() => {
    if (number%2==0) return res('randomly RESOLVED')
    return rej('randomly REJECTED')
  }, 2000)
})

const async_promise = () => new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => { 
  try {
    const resolvedPromise = await mock_api()
    resolve(resolvedPromise)
  } catch (e) {
    reject(e)
  }
})
const classicPromise = () => new Promise((resolve, reject) => { 
  mock_api()
  .then(resolve)
  .catch(reject)
})

const makeAsyncRequest = async () => {
  try {
    const data = await async_promise()
    console.log('ASYNC AWAIT RESOLVE', data)
  } catch (e) {
    console.log('ASYNC AWAIT ERR', e)
  }
}
makeAsyncRequest()

classicPromise()
.then(r => console.log('PROMISE CHAIN RESOLVE', r))
.catch(e => console.log('PROMISE CHAIN ERR', e))
```

Answer (score 0):

Because of you resolve before reject so it cannot run into reject,

You can use:

```
if (printResult) {
  resolve(printResult)
} else {
  reject(console.log('Error'))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can catch exceptions and return them as rejected Promises

```
function asyncFunc() {
try {
    doSomethingSync();
    return doSomethingAsync()
    .then(result => {
        ···
    });
} catch (err) {
    return Promise.reject(err);
}
```

}

Always check for err if there is any err return a promise (example below)

```
    // Return new promise 
return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    // Do async job
    request.get(options, function(err, resp, body) {
        if (err) {
            reject(err);
        } else {
            resolve(JSON.parse(body));
        }
    })
})
```